# How to get/see output of Lua lisner when executing script with Tshark

Tags: ssl, lua, tshark

I am new to Lua, I want Certificates data So I run below Lua Lisner code:

```
do
   local file = assert(io.open('data.txt','wb'))
   tap = Listener.new(nil, "ssl.handshake.certificate");
   Cert_info = Field.new("ssl.handshake.certificate");
   function tap.packet(pinfo, buffer, userdata)
     local cert = Cert_info();
     print("hi".. cert )
     file:write(cert.value);
   end 
end
```

Using Command> `tshark -r sslcert.pcap -X lua_script:certinfo.lua`

but I didn't get any output on console screen and in file too.
It just display all packets in `sslcert.pcap` file

Please Help me to see what info (`cert.value`) writes in file.